# Can not clone app from bitbucket by ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

When I clone my app from bitbucket on server, I can not.
my clone command is here

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:kyohei0423/bookpicks.git
```

this is some messages as an answer

```
Cloning into 'bookpicks'...
fatal: 'bitbucketkyohei0423/bookpicks.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I check that can log in by ssh
I logged in ssh

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as kyohei0423.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

What do I try any more?
Pleas tell me.

thanks

Comment: You should probably show your clone command. How else do you expect to get help?

Comment: It seems there's something wrong with your clone command...

Comment: thank you for advises
I show my clone command

Comment: post the debug log with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@bitbucket.org:kyohei0423/bookpicks.git`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can try using the HTTPS URL provided by BitBucket, which looks something like https://user@bitbucket.org/owner/project.git 
This method is password-based, and allows you to work without having to configure SSH access.